# Nginx running, but page is blank

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to configure a MunkiReport (https://github.com/munkireport/munkireport-php) site on an Ubuntu server hosted in DigitalOcean. I have PHP and MySQL installed and configured. When I navigate to my webroot, I get a successful message back from nginx.

My webroot is `/usr/share/nginx/html` and I'm using `/usr/local` as my repo for both Munki and MunkiReport. I put a symlink for the `/usr/local/report/public` folder into `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

Here is my nginx configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`) file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location /report {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/public;
        autoindex off;
        location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files $uri =404;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /munki_repo/ {
      alias /usr/local/munki_repo/;
      autoindex off;
      auth_basic "Restricted";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
server {
 if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

I have an `.env` file at the root of my MunkiReport folder which contains the configuration information (MySQL database connection) inside of it.

When I navigate to the `https://example.com/report` location, nothing loads. The console doesn't show any errors either, it's just blank.

Comment: Note the trailing slashes in the `munki_repo` config.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, I fixed that. Still don't know why the `/report` location won't load though.